# Is there a way to change the size of <w:lvlText w:val=" %1"/> for docx

Tags: xml, ms-word

I am updating a template of a Word document that uses styles I have adapted to include text before numbers in multilevel list in order to add that text automatically during preparing documents. I’ve added some new list styles, and at the field “Enter formatting for numbers: “ before number I’ve added some text, for example ‘Recommendation 1’ that I’ve linked to a style. When users clicks on that style, word automatically enter the word Recommendation and the appropriate number in sequence. 
Now there is a requirement to add some new styles, with longer text before the number. For example I need to put ‘Partially Reiterated Recommendation’ before number, but there is not possible because word has the limitation of only 30 characters on this field. I’ve tried to edit in in `numbering.xml` file at `<w:lvlText w:val="Partially Reiterated Recommend  %1"/>` but after I’ve completed the sentence by adding more characters here, the docx file can’t opened anymore. 
If there is a way I can make it longer input than 30 characters here, please explain it here. 
Sincerely, 
Shqipe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize Word multilevel list options with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756921/customize-word-multilevel-list-options-with-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is a limitation built into the way Word handles its automatic numbering.

Unfortunately, this can't be solved with a style. Possibly, the requirement can call for an abbreviation of the longer term?

If the final document needs the full text, when the document is "finalized", the numbering could be converted to static text then a Find/Replace run on the abbreviation to expand it to the full term.