# Customize Word multilevel list options with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am updating a template of a Word document that uses several styles I have adapted to include text before numbers in multilevel list in order to add that text automatically during preparing documents. I’ve added some new list styles, and at the field “Enter formatting for numbers: “ before numbers I’ve added some text, for example ‘Recommendation 1’ that I’ve linked to a style. When users clicks on that style, word automatically enter the word Recommendation and the appropriate number in sequence.

Now there is a requirement to add some new styles, with longer text before the number. For example I need to put ‘Partially Reiterated Recommendation’ before number, but there is not possible because word seems to has the limitation of only 22 characters on this field.

Is there a way to solve this issue (put a string longer than 22 character in “Enter formatting for numbers: “ field) with the help of VBA?

Comment: VBA would appear to have the same limitation regarding the numberformat property of a style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of the Word application and how auto numbering works. There is no possibility to do what is suggested as part of a style. VBA can't do things that aren't supported by the Word application, it can only "automate" the actions normally done by users.

You might try asking in an end-user group about work-arounds. Two possibilities come to mind, right off-hand:

1. Use an abbreviation, instead. If the abbreviation should be written out in a "final version" of the document, using VBA it would be possible to convert the numbering to text then use Find and Replace to replace the abbreviation with the full text.
2. Use `ListNum` fields for the numbering. These can be positioned anywhere in the text. VBA code can be used to insert the text plus the field code.

Comment: Thank you Cindy! We decided to use abbreviations, as I finally got sure it is not possible to solve that as it was required.